Change default Locale in Angular 17
How can I set the default locale in Angular 17?
In angular.json I added
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
  ....
        "i18n": {
          "sourceLocale": "it-IT"
        }
      },

in main.ts
import localeIt from '@angular/common/locales/it';
import localeItExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/it';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
  registerLocaleData(localeIt, 'it-IT',localeItExtra);

and in package.json
"@angular/localize": "^17.3.2",

but when in a template I write
 test number {{12.234|number}} test currency {{45.657|currency}}

I get
test number 12.234 test currency $45.66
instead of
test number 12,234 test currency €45.66
where am I wrong?

I followed the below steps.

run the below command to add angular localize

command
ng add @angular/localize


In the bootstrap application, we can add the below confiuration { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT' } into the providers array

code
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT' }],
});


I did the same thing you provided, I added the registerLocaleData

code
...
import { Component, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import localeIt from '@angular/common/locales/it';
import localeItExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/it';

registerLocaleData(localeIt, 'it-IT', localeItExtra);
...

full code
/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />

import { CommonModule, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { Component, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import localeIt from '@angular/common/locales/it';
import localeItExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/it';

registerLocaleData(localeIt, 'it-IT', localeItExtra);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    test number {{12.234|number}} test currency {{45.657|currency}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT' }],
});

Stackblitz Demo
